# Trouble filtering information with relational databases in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on my first project (a project management system) to understand PHP and MySQL better. I currently have 3 tables in my database, one that lists all the projects ('projects' table), one that stores the users username and password ('users' table) and then a third, small 'permissions' table that is meant to filter out what projects a user can see from the projects table.

The third 'permissions' table consists of an unique id, and then a "user_id" and a "project_id" in the other two columns. The "user_id" references the id of the user in the "users" table, and the "project_id" references the id of a project in the projects table.

Note that more than one user can have access to a single project, that's why there isn't just a single column for this in the projects table, and I read that using comma separated lists for the multiple usernames is a bad way to go about it. As such I have set up foreign keys on "user_id" and "project_id" that reference the id of each accordingly.

Now I'm not sure if this is a good way to set things up but it seems okay in my head.

Really what I want to do is retrieve all the projects a certain user has access to. So something kind of like (but obviously works):

```
SELECT * FROM projects WHERE user_id = 3;
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Something to do with the join command but I could never get it right.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Apologies for the ambiguity, gets a bit tricky to explain.

Essentially I just want a way to filter what rows are displayed from the projects table by the user_id in the users table (note again more than one user can access a project so I can just put a "user_id" column in the projects table and leave out the third table altogether).

My tables are pretty much like so:

projects:

```
|id|project_title|project_notes|project_status|
|1 |A Project    |Some Notes   |Finished      |
|2 |A 2nd Project|Some more... |In Progress   |
```

users:

```
|id|username|password|
|1 |johndoe |*********|
|2 |benhill |*********|
```

permissions:

```
|id|user_id|project_id|
|1 |1      |2         |
|2 |2      |2         |
```

user_id = id from users table.
project_id = id from projects table.

Then in HTML/PHP I only want to retrieve the projects that a user has access too.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes.  I'm sure there is a simple way but without being able to visualize your data, it's difficult to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your question isn't very clear but I assume you want to have a single query to find all project that a particular user has access to, you can simply join up the tables with the id as such:

```
SELECT * from projects INNER JOIN permissions ON 
projects.id = permissions.project_id WHERE 
permissions.user_id = 3
```

Assume the user you are looking for has id of 3

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty much it. I had been playing around with the JOIN command but my structure was wrong. Sorry for the lack of clarity in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
Users (Id, Name)
Projects (Id, Name)
Permissions (UserId, ProjectId)
```

and you want to "retrieve all the projects a certain user has access to", and you have the user id stored in a variable `$userId`, you could use a simple query like this:

```
select * from Projects pr  
join Permissions pe on pr.Id = pe.ProjectId
    and pe.UserId = $userId
```

Google around for more info on SQL syntax and joins. Here's a link I just found that looks like a good place to start: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Thanks Mark, I did intend to store the user name in a variable just as you said. I will take a look at that link to, it's all still a little confusing to me. Thanks again.